# BigQuery: How to use run_date in the query when back-filling

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I want to take data from yesterday's firebase analytics events table, transform the data and update an existing partitioned table with the same suffix as the origin events table.
For the destination table, I'm able to use a template: `shares_{run_time-24h|"%Y%m%d"}`
But in the query itself, all I could think of was:

```
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Which works great when running manually but obviously generates yesterday's date when I use backfill (rather than the backfill `run_date`)
I tried using `@run_date` w/ & w/o offset but it's not a valid query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to pass `@run_date` as an argument to `FORMAT_DATE`:

```
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', @run_date)
```

This works since `@run_date` has type `DATE`, so you can use it wherever a `DATE` expression is valid.

Comment: it should but it produces an error: `Undeclared query parameters`

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', @run_date)
```

Actually this method works. Working on this, i had a few problems like @SagiLow said, 'Undeclared query parameters'. It might be because @run_date cannot manipulate dates and operate between days. Therefore, while in the queries constructor it does not work, in the backfill scheduling this works, executing for each day the query on the exact day (do not forget that you do not need the INTERVAL because the tables already exist).

Answer (score 0):

I already marked the answer above as correct, but I just wanted to add another interesting use case as part of this thread. I created below query to do a backfill on **Daily Active Users**. The query can then be used as a BQ's "schedule query". It contains the `@run_time`-variable (and not `@run_date`, but you could also have used that). Note: As the query contains a variable, you can only test this in the Scheduled Query's view, and not in BigQuery's IDE.

Destination table:
`daus_1dayactiveusers_BackFillTest{run_time|"%Y%m%d"}`

Query:

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE(@run_time)) AS current_date,
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(DATE(@run_time), INTERVAL - 3 DAY)) AS beg_date,
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(DATE(@run_time), INTERVAL - 2 DAY)) AS end_date,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(DATE(@run_time), INTERVAL - 2 DAY)), TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(DATE(@run_time), INTERVAL - 3 DAY)), HOUR) AS hours_diff,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS uniq_users
FROM
  `<>.analytics_12345679810.<>`
WHERE
  event_name = 'user_engagement'
  AND event_date >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(DATE(@run_time), INTERVAL - 3 DAY))
  AND event_date < FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(DATE(@run_time), INTERVAL - 2 DAY))
  AND platform = "ANDROID"
```